# Which port does the RX100M3 use Liveview?

Tags: camera, sony, liveview

I'm developing on a SONY camera RX100M3. I want to know on which port does the camera use to return pictures during Liveview? is it on the same port to spend requests (port : 8080/sony/camera)?

I'm using 2 WiFi adaptors, one is connected to my box and the other to the camera. I have rerouted with "iptables" to redirect every packets coming form  port 8080 to 192.168.122.1:8080/sony/camera. I am sending request to 192.168.1.46:8080/sony/camera (first WiFi adaptor).

Actually I’m able to spend requests to the camera with the "pysony" library, take pictures, videos, Zoom In and Zoom out. But I can't get back the Liveview from the camera.

I hope I have been enough clear.

Answer (score 0):

When you call "startLiveview" it will return the URL to the live view stream in the response, which contains the port number.

```
{
   "result": [
        "http://ip:port/liveview/liveviewstream"
   ],
   "id": 1
}
```

Not sure what platform you are working on, but if it's Android or iOS have you taken a look at the CameraRemoteSampleApp project that comes with the SDK?  It contains sample code on how to start and display the live view stream.

Comment: I am using it on a WebApplication, i have already successfully get the liveview on the web page, so everything is working.

I want to use it at distance.
I get this when I start Liveview : http://192.168.122.1:8080/liveview/liveviewstream. So in theory I just have to redirect the port 8080 to the first adaptor IP.